# media query for responsive design not triggered on desktop

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I'm trying to create media queries that will set the css on a desktop distinct from the css for mobile.  Regardless of how small the window is made on a desktop I want the desktop css to be distinct from the mobile css.  I thought setting the min-width to 800px would force the first media query.

```css
html,body{
    min-width:800px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
  #flex{
    display:flex;
  }
  
  .item{
    font-size:3vw;
    color:blue;
    width:30vw;
    height:250px;
    border:solid black 2px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 799px) {
    html,body{
        min-width:unset;
        width:100vw;
    }
    
    #flex{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='flex'>
      <div class='item'>some text a</div>
      <div class='item'>some text b</div>
      <div class='item'>some text c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your class is `item` but your selector uses `items`. Other than that, the media query works in your example.

Comment: thanks for catching the typo but the second media query runs on a desktop when the screen is made smaller then 800px.  How do I prevent that?

Comment: The second media query _will not work_ on a desktop unless the actual, physical display is less than 799px wide. Resizing the browser will make no difference since you are using `max-device-width` instead of `max-width`. What makes you think the query is being triggered on a desktop browser?

Comment: when I make the desktop browser window smaller than 800px the second media query is triggered. How do I prevent that?  I want to run a different set of css instructions depending on whether I'm on a desktop or mobile

Comment: The second query _is not being triggered_ when you resize your browser. I have added `color: red` to your second query. See how the text never turns red?

Comment: I think you may have the logic the wrong way around. If you want the second query to be used by screens larger than 800px, use `min-width: 800px`. For screens smaller than 800px, use `max-width: 800px`.

Comment: thanks, b ut I think I just need to keep the css but remove the media query in the first case.  The second media query is for mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{
    min-width:800px;
}


  #flex{
    display:flex;
  }
  
  .item{
    font-size:3vw;
    color:blue;
    width:30vw;
    height:250px;
    border:solid black 2px;
  }


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 799px) {
    html,body{
        min-width:unset;
        width:100vw;
    }
    
    #flex{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='flex'>
      <div class='item'>some text a</div>
      <div class='item'>some text b</div>
      <div class='item'>some text c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```